# How do I add a button listener in Java?

Tags: java

I want to add a button listener in Java so that when the user just presses `enter` the button gets pressed.

I tried adding this action listener to the button I had creeated:

```
String guessText = txtGuess.getText();
JTextField txtGuess = new JTextField();
txtGuess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          checkGuess();
      }
  });
```

This is the whole function:

```
public void checkGuess() {
    String guessText = txtGuess.getText();
    JTextField txtGuess = new JTextField();
    txtGuess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              checkGuess();
          }
      });
    String message = "";
    int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText);
    if (guess < theNumber)
        message = guess + " is too low. Try again.";
    else if (guess > theNumber)
        message = guess + " is too high. Try again.";
    else {  
        message = guess + " is correct. Let's play again!";
        newGame();
    }
    lblOutput.setText(message);
}
```

However when my gui comes up and I press 'enter' after entering the input, nothing happens. I have to physically click the `Guess` button, which is what I was trying to avoid!

This is the window I created:

[image]

I want the user to enter a number and hit enter and have that click the `Guess` button. Help! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just so you know: a JTextField is not a button, it is, as the name implies, a TextField.
Also, your code makes no sense at all. each time you run checkGuess, you'll create another JTextField to which you add the method. First of all: add the actionListener to a button, there are more appropriate listeners for JTextFields if you want to listen to that. Don't add the method your field declaration is in to your actionListener ...

Comment: A button listener should trigger ... *IF THE BUTTON IS IN FOCUS WHEN THE USER HITS "ENTER"*.  Q: Do you want "Enter" to trigger "submit", regardless of which control has focus?

Comment: I've updated the OP with a screen shot of the window I created. What I want is for the user to enter a number into the text field and hit `enter` and have the `Guess` button get clicked.

When I go to the WindowBuilder and double click the `Guess` button it takes me to that function that I posted in the OP. Thanks for the clarification, and I'd like to know how to do this right!

Comment: OK, so you want to trigger "submit" if *EITHER* enter (focus on text field) *OR* button click (by definition, button will be in-focus).  In that case, follow Blank's advice: "I would add an ActionListener to the button as well as an ActionListener to the text field."  Please be sure to "upvote" and "accept" Blank's response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I would assume you want to reserve the right to apply the same code when enter is pressed as if the button were pressed.

To do this, I would add an ActionListener to the button as well as an ActionListener to the text field. Then have both of these ActionListeners trigger a return input which is checked against the randomly generated number.

The ActionListener method of the JTextField naturally triggers when the enter key is pressed.

Currently you have a method which returns and checks the input text and creates a new text field. You appear to do this in a recursive manner, rather than this you could simply have a method similar to this:

```java
private JTextField txtGuess;

private void initialiseTextField(){//Initialises a textField to be used for all inputs.
    txtGuess = new JTextField();
    txtGuess.addActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          checkGuess();
        }
    }
}

public void checkGuess() {
    String guessText = txtGuess.getText();
    txtGuess.setText("");//Empties the contents of the text field.
    String message = "";
    int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText);
    if (guess < theNumber)
        message = guess + " is too low. Try again.";
    else if (guess > theNumber)
        message = guess + " is too high. Try again.";
    else {  
        message = guess + " is correct. Let's play again!";
        newGame();
    }
    lblOutput.setText(message);
}
```

In order for this to work, you will need to declare txtGuess as an attribute of the class. You can do this with the line:

```java
private JTextField txtGuess;
```

I have it set to private but it should work if it is public.

The initialiseTextField method initialises the text fields conditions for the whole class, meaning new JTextFields are not made each time text is entered.

This should, hopefully, sort your problem out. Ask me if you need more help.

Note: I have only provided an example of how to check the input with the enter key, you will still need to create the button yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck. Maybe I used your example wrong? When I enter text into the window, clicking enter still doesn't do anything. Would you mind taking a look at my code and letting me know what I'm doing wrong?

https://pastebin.com/86EHupMy

Comment: Okay. My original code had some flaws and I think I have ironed it out. The problem was that the initialiseTextField method was never called. But I added it to your constructor. https://pastebin.com/viQ2uHzK

Comment: BAM!!! That did it. Thank you SO much for your help!!! This is my first ever attempt at a GUI application with Java. I'm pretty stoked to have this working!